# How to add a p-value to a correlation table while using model summary package in r?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, modelsummary

I was able to create a correlation table with 13 variables but based on my task I need to include p-values with this correlation table. I used data summary_correlation from the model summary package and was able to create a publish ready table. I couldn't find anything online that helped in adding p-values.

I wish I can be of more help by posting my code but the data is research sensitive.

I was expecting a way to add a p-value column to the end of my table.

Comment: Hey man. Did you try to use the `cor.test()$p.value` method? Lol, not really a method, but if you map this argument to your variables you should be able to extract the p values and add them to your data.

Comment: please add a dummy dataste (ie same number of columns or etc) if you cant provide data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to add p values, but `datasummary_correlation()` allows users to submit arbitrary correlation functions. This makes it relatively easy to hack your way there. For example:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(correlation)

dat = mtcars[1:5, 1:5]

fun = function(x) {
    out = correlation(x)
    stars = c("*" = .2, "**" = .15, "***" = .05)
    p = modelsummary:::make_stars(out$p, stars)
    out$r = sprintf("%.2f%s", out$r, p)
    out = as.matrix(out)
    return(out)
}

datasummary_correlation(dat, method = fun)
```

|  | mpg | cyl | disp | hp | drat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 1 | -.98*** | -.86 | -.95** | .51 |
| cyl | -.98*** | 1 | .89 | .91 | -.59 |
| disp | -.86 | .89 | 1 | .90 | -.87 |
| hp | -.95** | .91 | .90 | 1 | -.60 |
| drat | .51 | -.59 | -.87 | -.60 | 1 |

Comment: So with this functon of using stars, it's saying that those marked with "***" are significant with a 0.05 confidence, "**" significant with a 0.15 confidence, and so on?

Comment: Exactly. Of course, you can modify the function to get exactly the info you want, including just the numeric p values.

Comment: How would you make the method as a spearman correlation, with the function being present?

Comment: Please read the documentation `?correlation::correlation` and refrain from changing the question once posted or asking new questions in comments.